# What is the purpose of "RST" flag?

Tags: tcp, port, wireshark

I scanned my metasploitable machine for open ports from Kali using Nmap and captured the traffic using Wireshark and noticed that for every SYN packet sent to an open port, a RST packet was sent as well. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [RFC 793 3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793.txt) to learn more about reset packets. In your case, the explanation is :

> ```
> 1.  If the connection does not exist (CLOSED) then a reset is sent
> in response to any incoming segment except another reset.  In
> particular, SYNs addressed to a non-existent connection are rejected
> by this means.
> ```